# How to configure frame size in net/http for HTTP2

Tags: http, go, http2

I am trying to set the frame size to 16 MB in HTTP/2 Server using net/http library. Default size is 16 KB.

Tried following:

```
http2Server = http2.Server{
MaxReadFrameSize: 2 << 24 -1,
}
_ = http2.ConfigureServer(srv, &http2Server)
```

But still getting the frame size as 16 KB on client side (verified by printing length of response body). Is there any other way to set the Max Frame Size on Client and Server side ?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but what do you expect from this? For most HTTP/2 implementations I expect a very bad performance. They will try to allocate the 16MB frames at once on the heap instead of streaming them, which has a huge cost.

Answer (score 0):

`2<<24` is ~32MB, you probably want `1<<24-1`